# jQuery function .val() does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to update the value of the div block

`<div id="likeVal">Likes: @Model.Likes</div>`

after making an Ajax call as below:

```
 $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     async: false,
     url: "/Media/VideoLike?likes=" + likes + "&id=" + id
 }).done(function(data) {
     $("#likeVal").innerHTML = data.likes
 });
```

but the value in the block does not get updated. However when I use `document.getElementById("#likeVal").innerHTML = data.likes;` the value gets changed. I know that `document.getElementById` returns a `DOM object`. I have used the jQuery function in another Ajax call that I made here:

```
}).done(function(notice) {
            if (notice.error || notice.isLastBlock) {
                displayStatusMessage(notice.message);
                if (notice.isLastBlock) {
                    $("#assetId").val(notice.assetId);
                    $("#detailsPanel").show();
                }
                return;
            }
```

It works fine and the value get's updated in the div block. What am I doing wrong in the first Ajax call?

Comment: `div`does not have a value attribute that you can set.

Answer (score 2):

You are using wrong method for that.

[jQuery.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) gets/sets you value of form field. You should use [jQuery.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) to get/set content of element.

Comment: @AhmedMujtaba read my answer again. I didn't say that you should use that method.

Comment: just pass the value in `.val()` which you want to set.

Comment: @Elon infact it did work. So from what I understand, jQuery.val() only works for input elements with the 'value' tag. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, exactly like that.